# Transport Rule to Block External Auto-Forward Does Not Work - Exchange Online

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Has anyone tried following this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mitchelatmicrosoft/2015/05/03/exchange-online-blocking-auto-forward-messages-to-external-recipients/) to block auto-forwarding to external recipients?

I tried but doesn't work. Found that the transport rule is not hitting the message in the trace.

I know it can be done by disabling the auto-forward from remote domain. But I want to do it using a transport rule as I want to keep some exceptions.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!